# Novella/short book involving teleportation, ghosts and a magic tree

Tags: story-identification, novella

All I remember is it's some sort of cross between fantasy and sci-fi. I seem to remember there is a teleporter in it that has created some sort of monster. And there are some ghost like creatures that can only be killed by sticks harvested from some magical tree.

Sounds like a dream or a bad trip I know, but i swear I remember it! I don't believe it was a long book. Possibly a novella.

Comment: When would this have been published, roughly?

Comment: I've no idea in the publication date. I remember it being read in my last year of primary school. So the best I can do is pre-1999.

Comment: Not sure about the teleporter, but ghosts defeated by sticks or wood is a plot device in the "Rebecca's World" by Terry Nation - if it's the same then this is possibly a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/199108/childrens-book-story-about-ghosts-allergic-to-wood

Comment: Very unlikely, but Hexwood by Diana Wynne Jones? For the fix of sci fi/fantasy, the creation aspect, and the trees being relevant.

Comment: This was the first thing which came to my mind, but it has been 15+ years since I read it: [Enid Blyton, The Faraway Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Faraway_Tree)